# How to display apache manual on Windows XP

Tags: apache, installation, manual

I have installed apache 2.2 on Windows XP.  I amended the conf to include an alias for /manual, and added a Directory section to give the path read permissions.  I can access the page via //localhost/manual but it just shows unformatted text listing the other index.html files for different languages.  //localhost/manual/index.xml fails to find entities like &httpd.major;

How do I read the supplied manual?

Comment: Link or screenshot of the page please

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and figured it out.

In httpd.conf, uncomment lines with

```
mod_negotiation
extra/httpd-languages.conf
extra/httpd-manual.conf
```

restart server
reload page (cache will bite you)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to to run it from your server? They have several formats available including [PDF](http://apache.cs.utah.edu//httpd/docs/httpd-docs-2.2.14.en.pdf)